# Android Studio Gradle not Syncing

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-manifest

I'm very new to Android Studio and I'm basically trying to open an existing project that I had downloaded and compile/run it. I am getting the following error when Gradle attempts to sync...

```
Error:Cannot read packageName from /Users/Amanda/Desktop/MyProject/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
```

I have researched online and have tried several solutions, none of which have fixed my problem :/ I have also tried to "invalidate caches and restart" but it did not work either...

This is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="me.amanda.myproject.app">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="My Project">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".resourceListing"
            android:label="My App Listing">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ListApps"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list_apps">
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
</manifest>
```

My build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

}
dependencies {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

some times `clean` cant delete some of build folder files.

try these steps :

1- make a copy of your manifest file and delete your manifest file from project.

2- delete your `app/build` folder.

3-then clean your project

4- add the manifest file again to `src/main` directory

5- clean the project again

6- rebuild the project

Comment: Cleaning the project should delete the build folder on its own

Comment: i had an experience on windows when the clean couldn't and wouldn't delete some build folder files in windows OS like they are locked or sth.

Comment: Where is the manifest file you wrote its content ? Whats its path ?

Answer (score 0):

Set your `packageName` as `applicationId`in your `build.gradle` file.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
```

---

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "me.amanda.myproject.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.1"
}
```

Now, when you build apk your `packageName` will replace with **defaultConfig > applicationId**